# How to disable blue shadow in scrolling (android apps).

Tags: android, shadow

I have tried below things to disable the blue shadow while scrolling

All of this doesn't work:

```
android:fadingEdge="none"
android:background="@null"
android:cacheColorHint="@null"
```

Comment: accept answer if your problem have been resolved

Answer (score 20):

Use this in your XML `ScrollView`:

```
android:overScrollMode="never"
```

You can set to "always", "never", or "ifContentScrolls".

Comment: Thanks that shadow looked annoying to me Even though every app seems to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that @null is the same as nothing. Try setting the values to entirely transparent: like this:

```
android:background="#00000000"
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
```

Answer (score 1):

use below attribute for `ListView` to stop scrolling shadow

```
android:scrollingCache="false"
```

`android:fadingEdge="none"` is used to stop black background on scrolling

Answer (score 1):

Try to use as below

```
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
```